# How to avoid short showing of LoginScreen before t jumps to next while reads from memory key?

Tags: ios, objective-c, storyboard

I am trying to implement login screen before user enters app (when user registers I remember some key in `NSUserDefaults` and when next time starts app if there is key in `NSUserDefaults` I need to jump over login screen). I put inside my `LoginController` code like and it works but it always shows Login for a moment and then jumps to `AppController`. (I tried in `viewDidLoad` but then doesn't work). How to avoid this short showing of `LoginScreen` before it jumps to next?

```
- (void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    // ***************** reading key from memory **************************
    NSString * key = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]
                        stringForKey:@"key"];
    if(key != nil){
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"login" sender:self];
    }
    // **********************************************************************
}
```

If there is no key user pass through

`LoginController` = > `AppController`

if there is key it should to user looks like

`AppController`

but at the moment if there is key is

`LoginController` (very short time) => `AppController`

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is to have your AppController as your root view controller and in your viewDidLoad have a check to see if the user has been logged in. If not you can present a modal view controller (with no animation) to show your login screen. To the user it will look like they went straight to the login screen.

Comment: I used this approach at first in my app but it wasn't really working anymore when i wanted to "reset" the navigation stack and start from the beginning again (after logout/login). I ended up switching the main window.rootController to set the appropriate main view controller depending on login state. (but I am still not sure if this is the best way)